# Ruby on Rails SQL Query in view

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, phpmyadmin

I am working in a Rails Project and my problem is that for some reason the home view shows the SQL Query next to the book image. 
Here is the HTML code that shows the index view

```
<div id="books-index">
  <% @books.each_slice(4) do |book| %>
      <div class="row">
        <%= book.each do |book| %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <h3><%= book.title %></h3>
            <%= image_tag(book.coverpath) %>
            <%= link_to 'Read More', book_path(book), class:"btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the books controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @page_title = 'Add Book'
    @book = Book.new
    @category = Category.new
    @author = Author.new
    @publisher = Publisher.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
      flash[:notice] = "Book Created"
      redirect_to books_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  private
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :category_id, :author_id, :publisher_id, :isbn, :price, :buy, :format, :excerpt, :pages, :year, :coverpath)
  end
end
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `=` on your `book.each` iteration:

```
<% @books.each_slice(4) do |book| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% book.each do |book| %>
      ...
```

`<% ... %>` just evaluated, not printed.

`<%= ... %>` evaluated and printed.